# Nginx. Не работает блокировка по IP

Tags: nginx, ip, proxy

Выставлял подобные блоки

```
deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
```

и в секции server и в конкретных location и даже в секции http подключал файл через include: include       blockips.conf;
Но все ip-шники все равно попадают на сервер приложения.

Проблема, c одной стороны понятна: nginx как прокси-сервер сам стоит как бы
перед прокси  (хостинг heroku со своими дино-маршрутизаторами) и, видимо, к нему стучатся не указанные мной real_ip, а уже внутренние - от heroku.

В логах у меня выводятся все IP (реальный, прокси) и сейчас (после установки nginx перед моим приложением) в логах пишется сразу два IP: например, 212.22.93.185, 10.13.201.101
Первый - реальный, второй - уже от heroku. В общем все вторые IP всегда из этого диапазона: 10.x.x.x

Вопрос: как сказать nginx, чтобы он для сравнения IP клиента с указанными для блокировки брал не второй IP (внутренний от маршрутизатора heroku), а первый - настоящий?

---

В location секциях у меня стоит это:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Может это как-то влиять?

Comment: Покажите, каким образом/конфигом у вас в логах пишутся сразу два IP

Comment: Лог не от nginx, а от фреймворка приложения. Приложение на Go, фреймворк -  fiber. Формат задан мной в конфиге приложения: format = "FIBE[${time}] ${path} [${method} ${status} ] ${ips} ${bytesSent}b ${latency}\n"  . Переменная <ips> это как раз список всех IP клиента.

Comment: Этот список берется фреймворком из заголовков запроса, которые пишутся в переменную fiber.HeaderXForwardedFor.

Comment: [Документация Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) пишет, что доверять заголовку X-Forwarded-For нежелательно

Comment: Это понятно. Только как это к проблеме относится? Пока приложение работало без nginx - в  логах был только один IP - реальный. И мое приложение прекрасно блокировало всех кого нужно. Оно и сейчас блокирует через свое middleware. Но я то хотел, чтобы это было на уровне nginx. Я же его не для красоты обратным прокси установил.

Comment: В само конфиге nginx у меня также в location секциях стоят вот такие параметры:proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                   Может быть их нужно на уровне http также выставить? Или как они вообще влияют?

Comment: В nginx есть [ngx_http_realip_module](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html), можно с его помощью прописать доверенные IP-подсети Heroku и прописать реальный IP-адрес из заголовков

Comment: Ещё есть [ngx_http_geo_module](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html), с помощью которого можно сопоставить IP-адрес с определёнными адресами/подсетями, результат записать в переменную и по значению этой переменной выполнить какое-нибудь действие (но будет ли это работать хорошо, я пока что не уверен)

Comment: Ok. Я так понял без модуля ngx_http_realip_module действительно не обойтись, раз nginx выступает обратным прокси. Вот только неизвестно с какими модулями собран тот nginx, который на heroku идет в buildpack'е. Свой nginx туда не поставишь...

Answer (score 0):

Сработал вариант с использованием директив из модуля ngx_http_realip_module, как это и посоветовал **andreymal**.

```
set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

Правда, теперь у меня в логах отображаются два одинаковых внешних IP клиента.
Как я понял, по умолчанию в  ngx_http_realip_module используется директива:

```
real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;
```

И с ней у меня отображались два разных адреса (внешний и внутренний), но это не работало для блокировки.
Если кто-то понимает все эти нюансы, просьба дать свой разъясняющий ответ.